# Can I automatically 'Generate Scripts' in a SQL Server 2005 task?

Tags: sql-server, scripting

I'd like to automatically generate database scripts on a regular basis. Is this possible.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To generate script for an object you have to pass up to six parameters:

```
exec proc_genscript 
    @ServerName = 'Server Name', 
    @DBName = 'Database Name', 
    @ObjectName = 'Object Name to generate script for', 
    @ObjectType = 'Object Type', 
    @TableName = 'Parent table name for index and trigger',
    @ScriptFile = 'File name to save the script'
```

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2205291

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the SQL Server Management Objects (SMO).  There are objects for scripting that will assist in generating T-SQL scripts from database objects.  A good reference for this is ["Programming SQL Server 2005"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596004796) by Bill Hamilton.  Chapter 12 in particular references the SMO utility classes.